# Created div elements' random margins not working

Tags: javascript, css, html, margin

### Problem and source code

I'm trying to create `<div>`s within another `<div>` at the click of a button. When the button is clicked, a new inner `<div>` is created (within the outer `<div>`) with a unique id. I have this part working but here's where I'm running into an issue: I want each inner `<div>` to have a random `margin-top`.

#### Javascript

```
function pressButton() {
    number += 1;
    makeDiv(number);
};

function makeDiv(x) {
    var innerDiv = document.createElement("innerDiv" + x);
    outer.appendChild(innerDiv);
    innerDiv.setAttribute("style", "margin-top:" + Math.floor(Math.random()*51) + ";display:inline-block;width:48px;height:48px;background-color:#000;");
};
```

#### CSS:

```
#outer {
    position:absolute;
    white-space:nowrap;
    height:118px;
    overflow:auto;
    width:100%;
    padding:2px;
}
```

### Result (after button is clicked 4 times)

```
<div id="outer">
    <innerDiv1 style="margin-top:15;display:inline-block;width:48px;height:48px;background-color:#000;"></innerDiv1>
    <innerDiv2 style="margin-top:23;display:inline-block;width:48px;height:48px;background-color:#000;"></innerDiv2>
    <innerDiv3 style="margin-top:37;display:inline-block;width:48px;height:48px;background-color:#000;"></innerDiv3>
    <innerDiv4 style="margin-top:0;display:inline-block;width:48px;height:48px;background-color:#000;"></innerDiv4>
</div>
```

The result (which I got from inspecting the inner elements in my browser) looks like everything worked - all the `margin-top`s are random like I wanted. However, the visual result is this:

[image]

As you can see, the black inner `<div>`s all have the same `margin-top`. What am I doing wrong? How can I make the created `<div>`s all have random `margin-top`s?

Comment: Where is your `event handler` for `makeDiv`?

Comment: This is all I see with provided markup - [Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/SinisterSystems/2y5bJ/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/T929z/1/)

### Description

This happens, because you set the `display:inline-block;` property. This makes them all to be in one line, so they will allign to the `innerDivx` that has the highest `margin-top`.

Delete the `display:inline-block;` property and give them `float:left;`. If you want to keep the gap between them, also add `margin-left:5px;`. And don't forget that `margin-top`'s value needs a unit. I think you wanted to use `px`.

Also `<innerDivx>` is not a valid HTML tag. You should change them to a `<div>` and use `innerDivx` as an id attribute. Also your tags use almost the same CSS styles so you should put the same ones to a class and add the class instead.

### Full solution code

#### HTML

```html
<button id="button1">Add box</button>
<div id="outer"></div>
```

#### JavaScript

```js
var number = 0;

document.getElementById("button1").addEventListener("click", pressButton, false);

function pressButton() {
    ++number;
    makeDiv(number);
};

function makeDiv(x) {
    var innerDiv = document.createElement("div");
    outer.appendChild(innerDiv);
    innerDiv.className += " box";
    innerDiv.setAttribute("id", "innerDiv" + x);
    innerDiv.setAttribute("style", "margin-top:" + Math.floor(Math.random()*51) + "px;");
};
```

#### CSS

```css
#outer {
    position: absolute;
    white-space: nowrap;
    height: 118px;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 2px;
}

.box {
    float: left;
    width: 48px;
    height: 48px;
    background-color: #000;
    margin-left: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't mention above that I changed "inline-block" to "block" right after posting the question and it turned out the main issue was forgetting the "px" :D Thanks for the <div> advice!

Comment: You're awesome :D If you're around to read this, mind if I ask you a semi-related question? How do you make the outer div only show a horizontal scroll bar? (Or, how to make the inner divs be created horizontally, without a line break.)

Comment: @user3208943 I'm happy to answer. But if it doesn't connects to this question, then according to SO rules, you should ask it in a different question so everybody (not just me) can answer, and you will get the best answer.

Answer (score 3):

The CSS spec requires that a length (other than zero) that is missing a unit be treated as an error (and thus ignored). Therefore, add `px` to the end of your generated margin number, and all should be well.

Comment: [Doesn't work](http://jsfiddle.net/SinisterSystems/2y5bJ/1/) All divs are inheriting the `max` value.

Comment: Thanks! It was that simple! Dunno how I missed that :D

Comment: Forgot to mention that I also changed "display:inline-block" to "display:block" which, as the answers below mention, is also necessary :D Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2):

This is likely caused by the position model used for `inline-block` elements - they're all being vertically-aligned at their bottom line in a row.

I suggest that you simplify this and use `position: block` with `float: left`

http://jsfiddle.net/2y5bJ/4/

I also suggest that you stick to standard elements to ensure cross-browser compatibility - don't create your own elements called `innerDiv1` etc, but use `div` elements with unique IDs.

```
function makeDiv(x) {
    var innerDiv = document.createElement("div");
    outer.appendChild(div);
    innerDiv.setAttribute('id', 'innerDiv' + x);
    innerDiv.setAttribute("style", "margin-top:" + Math.floor(Math.random()*51) + "px;");
};
```

Comment: Creating an actual <div> was mentioned above but thank you for posting the syntax for it! :D

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no tag available with name

```
<innerDiv1>
```

This may be the cause.

Comment: @Nicholas Hazel Can I use the <innerDiv1>?